# Saving dtype = datetime[ns] data array to text using numpy gives unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've extracted some data from a data frame and want to save it as a text file

```
# df is my dataframe with col1, col2...., as column headers
X = df.col1[df['col3']<35].unique()
X[0:3]
>>array(['1998-01-07T11:00:00.000000000', '1998-01-06T23:00:00.000000000',
   '1998-01-28T11:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
np.savetxt('filename', X, delimiter=' ', header='Some Header')
```

I'm expected it to save the dates but instead, the file contains the first few lines as:

```
# Some Header 
8.841708000000000000e+17
8.841276000000000000e+17
8.859852000000000000e+1
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)'s default format for each field is `'%.18e'`, which is a floating point format.  Add the `fmt` argument to change the format, e.g.

```
np.savetxt('filename', X, fmt='%s', delimiter=' ', header='Some Header')
```